# Can't install ubuntu 20.04 on windows10

Tags: boot

I bought a usb with ubuntu 20.04, but I am unable to install it on my pc (and erase my windows 10).

When I put the usb on my laptop and hit the "grub" box, my computer pops a message with the following words: **This app can't run on your PC. To find a version for your PC, check with the software publisher.**

I disabled secure and fast boot, but to no avail. Though there's e boot box on my PC's bios, there's no USB option.

Can someone help me? I have windows 10 right now and wish to erase them and switch to Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

The way to use a bootable USB stick is to boot into it from the BIOS. You have to select the USB drive as the drive to boot from. If your BIOS doesn't have that option, you can try a DVD or any other option that the BIOS supports, or you can keep looking through the boot options until you figure out how to boot from the drive.

However, switching to Ubuntu entirely when you can't even boot to a bootable drive seems unwise, as it will likely be quite frustrating to figure out how to accomplish many tasks (or even how to get your system to boot, depending). You should probably either run off the live USB to see if you are OK with the system, or even dual-boot so that you can always go back to Windows if you need it.